# Mysqli print and show in browser from table

Tags: php, database, mysqli

My connection & sql queries have already been tested and they work.  I am just trying to print one column of data into my browser for output so I can test the rest of the database.  I am just trying to print one row and when I run the code, nothing shows up in the browser as output.  The database column name is "type" and there is a "1" in there for the user I am logging in with.  The login works but I am trying to read the integer in the database in order to direct it to a specific profile.  I can't get anything to printout from my table into the browser.

```
$role = "SELECT type FROM fp.user WHERE usname ='$username' AND pswd = '$password'";
$access = mysqli_query($link, $role);

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($access);

echo $row['type'];
```

Comment: What happens when you do `var_dump($row)`?

Comment: **WARNING:** When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. DO NOT use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, as it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: i changed it to var_dump.. it actually gave me an output of NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem with your query. You should check to see if `$access` is first false (Which would indicate a query failure), and echo out the error associated with the query.

```
$role = "SELECT type FROM fp.user WHERE usname ='$username' AND pswd = '$password'";
$access = mysqli_query($link, $role);

if ( !$access )
{
    echo 'There was a problem running this query: ', mysqli_error($link);
    exit;
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_row($access);
```

Also, according to the docs:

> Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero). Each subsequent call to this function will return the next row within the result set, **or NULL if there are no more rows.**

Check to make sure the user/password combo in the database is correct. Another issue could be that no user exists for that $username/$password combo.

Comment: So nothing gets echo'd when running the above code?

Comment: Then the most likely culprit is no rows matched. `$row` would be null.

Comment: the username and password.. i have already verified and i can sign in to the profile.. but im trying to make it role based.. so i have a type data column in my table that I need to set it to value in order to do if/else statements to bring up different profiles

Comment: Can you echo out `$role` and run that query directly on the database to ensure it returns the row you want?

Comment: it just echo's out the sql statement.. no real data from database

Comment: Yeah, but I'm saying, copy that query and run it on the database. (Using PHPMyadmin, or through the console). Make sure that query returns the row you're looking for.

Comment: So there's your issue @Andy. If `$row` is null, then no rows were matched. Check to make sure your query is correct. If there was a row in the database that exists, then your code would work.